# Variable declaration in postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to create variable with two  word separated by space in Postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
    Partner varchar(10) NULL,
    "[Partner Name]" varchar (200) NULL,
    "[Contract Number]" varchar(15) NULL,
    "[Customer Name]" varchar(150) NULL,
    "[Lease Start]" Date date NULL
From maintable
```

This is not working. How to give variables with 2 words separated by space. Please help

Comment: Tables have **columns** not "variables". The use of double quotes is correct to define a column name that contains a space (or other invalid characters like the square brackets). What are you trying to achieve with the invalid `from maintable` part? "*This is not working*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to populate the data in new table named test from other table named maintable with column names having spaces.

below is the syntax

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
as select col1 as  Partner ,
col2 as "Partner Name", 
col3 as "Contract Number", 
col4 as "Customer Name",
col5 as "Lease Start Date" from maintable;
```